# How to never let the keyboard dismiss on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have a little problem here with iOS 7. In my screen I have a `UITextView` and a corresponding keyboard  that in my code I set to be the first responder `[myTextView becomeFirstResponder]`, I have a navigation bar button that calls for an `UIActionSheet`. Now my problem is that every time I call to dismiss the action sheet, the keyboard also dismisses itself without me having to call `[myTextView resignFirstResponder]`. This only happens on iOS 7. Anybody knows how to prevent this from happening..?

Thanks.

Comment: What code do you use to dismiss the action sheet?

Comment: You could just assign your textview to be first responder again after dismissal of action sheet... I think `[myTextview becomeFirstResponder]` should work?!

Comment: @MikeS I didn't use any code to dismiss the action sheet because it automatically dismisses itself after selecting one of the options.

Comment: @Mario, that's what Im doing right now but I find it not good for User experience seeing the keyboard dismiss and show without any reason

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
      return NO;
 }
```

This should prevent the keyboard to dismiss itself.

**Note:** This method belongs to `UITextFieldDelegate Protocol`

Comment: I am using `UITextView

Comment: Oh, sorry...what about this method `- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView`. This method should be called to know if editing should end or not. It's part of `UITextViewDelegate`

Comment: Good idea, but no, doesn't work, keyboard still goes down and bugs after that.